# What are the prerequisites (particularly levels) of the various Bonus Series questlines?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Starting with Balmorra for the Empire or Taris for Republicans, every planet in The Old Republic features a *Bonus Series* quest chain. These quests often have a higher level requirement than the rest of the planet, as well as requiring that you've completed the 'primary' story arc of that particular world. They generally follow on to and 'wrap up' that planets storyline, and generally involve visiting several new quest hubs and doing a variety of additional quests.

Some of these Bonus Series, such as the ones on Balmorra and Tatooine are availiable immediately after you finish the planets primary storyline.

Others, such as Nar Shaddaa or Alderaan, are not availiable until much later. For example, Nar Shaddaa's bonus series is level 32, but an Imperial player will normally first go there around level 20.

**What are the level requirements for all of the planetary bonus series, as well as any other prerequisites (aside from having completed the main story arc of the planet in question)?**

Comment: Tatooine Bonus Series was available to me as soon as I reached the planet the first time, so I assume it's purely based on level.

Comment: I've got the Taris Bonus Series at 24.

Comment: I got the Republic Taris Bonus series as I left the planet at 21.

Comment: From my experiences on Taris, the Taris Bonus Series appears to be available as soon as you complete your first Class Quest series on Taris, return to your ship and use the terminal once (to officially end the first Class Quest Taris series), then return to the Taris spaceport to get the Bonus Series mission. IIRC, Tatooine and Alderaan may have ended the first class series for those planets before returning to your ship? So you might be able to get those Bonus Series missions before you leave the planet? Not sure about those two though.

Comment: @Mufasa  My wife was able to start the bonus series on Taris before returning to her ship. She was level 24 at the time. I was 26 and used the holoterminal on my ship, before she was like "Hey, there's another quest here!". Not sure if I just ran by it without seeing it, or if I had to use the holoterminal first. In case it matters, I'm a Jedi Knight and she's a Jedi Consular. Anyway, long-winded way of saying I don't think you have to use the terminal on your ship first.

Comment: @Sterno: My experience was with the Jedi Knight quest line. It could very easily be different for the Jedi Consular. I guess then, the answer is probably "it depends on your class exactly when, but it is always after your first class quest line for that planet is completed." Anyone disagree, or should we post that as an Answer? And does this apply for the high-level planet series too? (Personally, I have only made it to mid-30's so far.)

Comment: @Mufasa that conjecture is completely and provably false. Every planet has a bonus series. Each has, at a minimum, a level requirement. Some may have additional quest prerequisites, I'm unsure of that, but none of them should in *any* way interact with your class quest.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I'm confused. You say that Class Quest progress does not enable Bonus Series missions and you can prove it, yet that's exactly what you ask in this Question and in your comment about having proof you offer no proof. If you can prove it one way or the other, by all means, post your proof. Because apparently the rest of us aren't really sure and are just guessing at this point.

Comment: @Mufasa: Every planet has a 'primary' quest arc that contains a narrative after a fashion on that planet. This arc is *class agnostic*, and open to all players. That's the quest line I'm referring to. Now, per Powerlords comment, I may be incorrect about completing it being required to enable the bonus missions on a given planet, but I can say with a good deal of confidence that there is *at least* a level requirement, and that there may be other quest related prerequisites. I'm quite confident that it has nothing to do with the class quest because *it wouldn't make sense*...

Comment: (Cot'd)  given the nature of the Bonus Series - a series of quests that augments, continues, or completes the narrative began with the quests that are available to all players on a particular planet. As for proof of that specifically, I can say that I did the Taris bonus series before doing a single class quest on Taris.

Answer (score 1):

I verified, and it seems to answer your question, and doesn't go against what you already found (being able to get Nar Shadda around 32, and Taris at 21).

So based on [this link](http://www.torhead.com/search/bonus%20series):

- Alderaan: 37
- Balmorra: 12 for first one, 29 for the second one
- Belsavis: 47
- Hoth: 44
- Nar Shaddaa: 28
- Taris: 29 for Imperials, 12 for Republic
- Tatooine: 22
- Voss: 41

Comment: That's an Imperial/Republic distinction on Balmorra.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Empire Balmorra. I did no questing on Balmorra except for my class quest. I went back to Balmorra to do the bonus series at level 22 (expecting to have to do all the other quests -_-), and to my surprise I could start the bonus series. Bear in mind that I have not done any questing on Balmorra apart from my class quest.

My wife however, at level 22, was unable to talk to the chappie which hands out the bonus series. She had not completed her class quest. Once she had completed her class quest, she could do the bonus series.

It would appear that Balmorra has a level requirement but also requires you to complete your class quest.

With regards to your statement:

> "Some of these Bonus Series, such as the ones on Balmorra and Tatooine are availiable immediately after you finish the planets primary storyline."

...did you clear the Balmorra Class business? My experience has shown that the primary storyline had no bearing on my ability to start the bonus series.